# Android Bluetooth profiles missing with paired devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing, bluetooth-tethering

I have an Android 6.0 device and an Android 4.1 device.

I used Bluetooth to pair them (only a numeric code was shown, no input needed) and it worked, *I can send files via Bluetooth*.

However, when I click the paired device on either phone, *I can't see any profile*.

This is what I see:

[image]

As *Internet Access* is a crucial profile for tethering, it must be present.

Can you tell me why they are missing?

Comment: Have you enabled the "Bluetooth-Tethering" setting on either of the phones (the one which should share the connection)?

Comment: @Robert Yes, it says _Sharing Internet connection…_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my old Sony Xperia J phone [does not have](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/help/xperia-j-bluetooth-tethering-t2187561) this feature: either by hardware limitations or by [carrier modifications](https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/130129).